# Multiplicity of eigenvalues of a compact operator and explicit decay rate of the eigenvalues

Tags: operator-theory, eigenvalues

I already asked this on "Mathematics", but I guess (at least) Question 2 could be appropriate here as well.

Let's consider a selfadjoint compact operator $C\colon L^2[0,1] \rightarrow L^2[0,1],$ where $(L^2[0,1], ||\cdot||_{L^2[0,1]})$ stands for the hilbert space of measurable function $f\colon [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $\int_{[0,1]}f^2(x)\,\textrm{d}\lambda(x) < \infty$ with Lebesgue measure $\lambda.$

**Question 1:** What conditions $C$ has to fulfill such that the eigenvalues $(\lambda_j)_{j \in \mathbb{N}}$ of $C$ have multiplicity of one, meaning $\lambda_i \neq \lambda_j$ if $i \neq j$ with $i,j \in \mathbb{N}?$

**Question 2:** For compact operators $C$ we know that the sequence of eigenvalues $(\lambda_j)_{j \in \mathbb{N}}$ of $C$ belongs to $c_0$ and we know $(\lambda_j)_{j \in \mathbb{N}} \in \ell^2$ if $C$ is Hilbert Schmidt, $(\lambda_j)_{j \in \mathbb{N}} \in \ell^1$ if $C$ is nuklear and $(\lambda_j)_{j \in \mathbb{N}} \in d$ if $C$ has finite image. But do I know something about the explicit decay rate of the sequence of eigenvalues of $C$ if $C$ fulfills certain properties? - meaning e.g. $\lambda_j \sim j^{-3}$ for $j \rightarrow \infty$ or $\lambda_j \sim r^j$ with $r \in (0,1)?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt that you'll find a very general condition that requires multiplicity $1$, other than those that are essentially restatements of that fact.
There will be conditions related to particular forms of operators, e.g. 
 Sturm-Liouville integral operators.

Similarly, for explicit decay rates
you'll want something more explicit than one of these general classes.

Comment: Thanks. What about if we just focus on integral operators $C$ with $(C(x))(t) = \int_0^1c(s,t)x(s)\,\textrm{d}s, \forall x \in L^2[0,1], \forall t \in [0,1]$ where $\int_0^1\int_0^1c^2(s,t)\,\textrm{d}s\,\textrm{d}t < \infty?$ I took a look at integral operators of Sturm-Liouville type, unfortunately they are not useful for me.